# Replace values in list while keeping the original

Tags: python, list

I am starting in python and I have this little problem, I have 2 lists and I want to switch the 2 middle values to create 2 more list and have 4 in total, like this:

```
p1=[3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]
p2=[5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4]
s1=[3, 5, 3, 6, 4, 6]
s2=[5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4]
```

I made this code:

```
p1=[3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]
p2=[5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4]
s1=p1
s2=p2

for i in range(2,4):
    s1[i]=p2[i]
    s2[i]=p1[i]

print(s1)
print(s2)
```

The result is wrong, seems that 'p' and 's' are linked, how can i change it?:
[3, 5, 3, 6, 4, 6]
[5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4]

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing this:

```
s1=p1
```

You are saying: `s1` is a pointer to `p1`, if you modify `p1` you are also modifying `s1`

- You can use the builtin `list.copy()` method (available since Python 3.3)
- You can slice it: `new_list = old_list[:]`

there are multiple ways of coping values of list, take a look at:

[List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Answer (score 0):

`copy()` is all you need:

```
p1=[3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]
p2=[5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4]
s1=p1.copy()
s2=p2.copy()

for i in range(2,4):
    s1[i]=p2[i]
    s2[i]=p1[i]

print(s1)
print(s2)
```